# How to use where in Sequelize include when models are 2 relationships apart

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Supposing Players belong to Teams that belong to Leagues

Am trying to filter by player id and league id but below query returns only the player but returns null in team:

```
Team.hasMany(Player, { foreignKey: 'teamId' })
League.hasMany(Team, { foreignKey: 'leagueId' })
Team.belongsTo(League, { targetKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'leagueId' });
Player.belongsTo(Team, { targetkey: 'id', foreignKey: 'teamId'});

let player = await Player.findOne({
   where: {
       id: playerId
   },
   include: [
        {
            model: Team,
            include: [{
                model: League,
                where: { id: leagueId }
            }]
        }
     ]
});
```

Comment: do you have model relationships both ways for all three of them ? haOne belongsTo etc.....

Comment: yup I do have... edited my question to show the relationships

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you are missing a relationship, this worked for me

```
    Player.belongsTo(Team, ...)
    Team.hasMany(Player, { foreignKey: 'fk_name' })

    Team.belongsTo(League, { targetKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'leagueId' });
    League.hasMany(Team, { ... })
```